# How can I concatenate two counters (custom)

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter

I have two counters with me, so let's suppose for simplicity:

```
a = "this" : 2 , "is" : 3
b = "what" : 3 , "is" : 2
```

Now I want to concatenate the two counters like this:

```
concatenatedCounter = "this" : 2 , "is" : 3,2 , "what" : 3
```

Is there any way of doing it in Python?

Edit 1 : Solved the first issue, below is the new issue, please help :)

In the above result if I want the defaultdict to contain { 'this' : [2,0],'is':[3,2],'what' : [0,3]}), what changs would I need to make?

Comment: what does this have to do with a counter? Are you adding the 2 and the 3 or are you trying to just concatenate the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
In [38]: a = {"this" : 2 , "is" : 3}

In [39]: b = {"what" : 3 , "is" : 2}

In [40]: from collections import defaultdict

In [41]: collected_counter=defaultdict(list)

In [42]: for key,val in a.items():
    collected_counter[key].append(val)
   ....:     

In [43]: for key,val in b.items():
    collected_counter[key].append(val)
   ....:     

In [44]: collected_counter
Out[44]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'this': [2], 'is': [3, 2], 'what': [3]})
```

**Update:**

```
>>> keys=a.viewkeys() | b.viewkeys()
>>> collected_counter=defaultdict(list)
>>> for key in keys:
    collected_counter[key].append( a.get(key,0) )
...     
>>> for key in keys:
    collected_counter[key].append( b.get(key,0) )
...     
>>> collected_counter
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'this': [2, 0], 'is': [3, 2], 'what': [0, 3]})
```

Comment: In the above result if I want the defaultdict to contain { 'this' : [2,0],'is':[3,2],'what' : [0,3]}), what changs would I need to make?

Comment: @user1795516 see my updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = {"this" : 2 , "is" : 3}
>>> b = {"what" : 3 , "is" : 2}
>>> for k, v in chain(a.items(), b.items()):
        dd[k].append(v)


>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'this': [2], 'is': [3, 2], 'what': [3]})
```

Comment: Nice! just what I needed!

Comment: In the above result if I want the defaultdict to contain { 'this' : [2,0],'is':[3,2],'what' : [0,3]}), what changs would I need to make?

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
combinedValues = defaultdict(list)
for key in counterA.viewkeys() & counterB.viewkeys():
    combinedValues[key].extend([counterA[key], counterB[key]])
```

Comment: In the above result if I want the defaultdict to contain { 'this' : [2,0],'is':[3,2],'what' : [0,3]}), what changs would I need to make?